# jQuery Ajax function does not  complete call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, function

I wanted to make my register form use the $.ajax function instead of using the normal way - of redirecting the user to another php page.

I call this function:

```
function register(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "user/registerConfirm.php",        
    data:   "regUsername=" + document.getElementById("regUsername").value + 
        "&regPassword=" + document.getElementById("regPassword").value +
        "&myPassCheck=" + document.getElementById("myPassCheck").value +
        "&regEmail=" + document.getElementById("regEmail").value,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg){ 
         alert("Success!");
         alert(msg);
    },
    complete: function(msg){                        
        alert("Displaying return value now.." + msg);       
    },
    error: function(request, status, error) {           
        //alert(request.responseText);
        alert("Error, returned: " + request);
        alert("Error, returned: " + status);
        alert("Error, returned: " + error);
    }
});
}
```

When clicking on the submit button. However, the 'complete' function is never called, and neither are the other functions.

This is the php file is uses:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

require("../widgets/functions.php");
connectToDB();

// Check email
if (!filter_var(clean($_POST['regEmail']), FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
{   
    $error = 'Invalid email!';          
}
else
{               
    if ( clean($_POST['regPassword']) == clean($_POST['myPassCheck']) && clean($_POST['regPassword']) != NULL 
        &&  clean($_POST['regUsername']) != NULL && clean($_POST['regEmail']) != NULL ) // Register can be allowed
    {           
        // Check if their already is a user with the same name..
        $sql="SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE username='".clean(trim($_POST['regUsername']))."'";
        $result=mysql_query($sql);

        // Mysql_num_row is counting table row
        $count=mysql_num_rows($result);     

        if($count==1){
        // Their was already a user with this name!                         
            $error = 'Registration failed - username already taken..';
        }
        else if ( $count == 0 ){ 
        // Registration allowed, no user found with the same name               

            // Encrypt password
            $encryptPass = md5($_POST['regPassword']);

            $subject = "Confirmation registration";
            $message = '
                        <html>
                            <head>
                          <title>Registration at codexplained</title>
                        </head>
                            <body>
                                <p>Hello '.clean($_POST['regUsername']).',</p>

                                <p>Thank you for registering at our website!
                                </p>

                                <p>If you wish, you can now edit your profile, to change your display options and/or to upload your own profile image!<br />
                                We hope to see you commenting on our articles soon!<br />
                                If you wish to receive more information - Please contact us, or message any of our moderators.</p>
                                <hr />
                                <p>- Current moderators - <br />
                                Ruud<br />
                                Willem<br />
                                Quint
                                </p>
                                <hr />                              
                                </p>
                                - Contact details - <br />
                                Codexplained.tk<br />
                                Codexplained@gmail.com
                                </p>
                            </body>
                        </html>
                        ';
            $from = "Codexplained@admin.com";
            $headers = 'From: Codexplained'."\r\n";
            $headers  .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            $to = clean($_POST['regEmail']);
            if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) )
            {
                // Success
            }
            else
            {
                // Failed
            }
            // Insert data
            $query = "INSERT INTO `users` 
            (
            `Id` ,`Username` ,`Password` ,`Rank`,`E-mail` ,`PostAmount`, `ProfileImage`, `Ip`, `LastIP`
            )
            VALUES ( NULL , '".clean(trim($_POST['regUsername']))."' , '".$encryptPass."' , 'member', '".clean($_POST['regEmail'])."' , '0', 'none', '".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."' )      
            ";
            mysql_query($query)or die(mysql_error());

            $error = 'Registration completed!';
        }
    }
    else
    {           
        if ( clean($_POST['regPassword']) != clean($_POST['myPassCheck']) )
        {
             $error = 'Passwords do not match...';
        }
        else
        {
            $error = 'Registration failed - not enough data..';
        }
    }
}

echo $error;    

//mysql_close();
//header("location:../index.php?page=register");?>
```

This actually works - when pressing submit, and while entering the correct data it will in fact register the user, is just won't give any feedback - which is a problem.

I am hoping you can find what I missed.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Try this: `echo $error . 'TEST';`. Then you will definitely return something.

Comment: I just tested it out, using a seperate php file - this file was basically: echo 'test'; Nothing happened, so I can assume the bug is in the jQuery function.

Comment: Why are you using `dataType: "json",`?

Comment: Use something like firebug for firefox, or the javascript console to find out what happens to the request.

Comment: well what result do you get on normal request? display the output result

Comment: in the `echo` you should send the string converted to [JSON](http://www.json.org/). It should be double quieted like '"bla bla"'

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting any javascript errors? The ajax function is expecting a json response but by the look of it you are just returning a plain string which jQuery wont be able to parse into json.

Change the datatype to text and see if that works.

```
function register(){
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "user/registerConfirm.php",        
   data:   "regUsername=" + document.getElementById("regUsername").value + 
     "&regPassword=" + document.getElementById("regPassword").value +
     "&myPassCheck=" + document.getElementById("myPassCheck").value +
     "&regEmail=" + document.getElementById("regEmail").value,
   dataType: "text", // <-------- There
   success: function(msg){ 
       alert("Success!");
       alert(msg);
   },
   complete: function(msg){                        
       alert("Displaying return value now.." + msg);       
   },
   error: function(request, status, error) {           
       //alert(request.responseText);
       alert("Error, returned: " + request);
       alert("Error, returned: " + status);
       alert("Error, returned: " + error);
   }
 });
}
```

Comment: The problem in fact is - that not even the error function is being called - no alert messages are being displayed.

Comment: @Rudd do you see the request on the firebug console?

Comment: Yes, but are you getting any javascript errors in your browser? Have you tried changing dataType to text? Or you can just remove dataType and it will try to guess the right type.

Answer (score 0):

See http://json.org/ for the right syntax of *json*. In your Case, change the last line in the php script to:

```
echo '{"error": "'. $error .'"}';
```

Or use another datatype like *text*, see the answer of [Richard Dalton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5153520/1316280)